# how to get sequences of list of tuples

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, combinations, permutation

Given this is the input

`[(A,1),(A,2),(B,0),(C,2),(C,3)]`

the output should be:

```
[[(A,1),(B,0),(C,2)],[(A,2),(B,0),(C,2)],[(A,1),(B,0),(C,3)],[(A,2),(B,0),(C,3)]]
```

and its permutations

Comment: please describe what you have done so far and what was the problem.

Comment: what you have as output is not a valid list

Comment: does the order of the output groups matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `groupby` and `product`:

```py
from itertools import groupby, product

input = [("A", 1), ("A", 2), ("B", 0), ("C", 2), ("C", 3)]

groups = groupby(input, key=lambda x: x[0])

output = [list(p) for p in product(*[item for item in (list(i) for g, i in groups)])]

print(output)
```

Output:

> [[('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('C', 2)], [('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('C', 3)], [('A', 2), ('B', 0), ('C', 2)], [('A', 2), ('B', 0), ('C', 3)]]

Comment: The output doesn't match what is in the question

Comment: just because the product outputs tuples and not lists? well, I edited to cast them to a list...

Comment: Oh, the order is different, too...